# I need to know why the following MySQL is not giving me the Strings I AES_ENCRYPTed

Tags: mysql

Here's the Schema for MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE prevent(
  remoteAddr TINYBLOB NOT NULL,
  logTime TINYBLOB NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT prevent VALUES (
  AES_ENCRYPT('just a lame test','Wt@F4z5u#r'),
  AES_ENCRYPT(NOW(),'b$Do^rK32C')
);
```

Now the Simple query:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(remoteAddr,'Wt@F4z5u#r') remoteAddr, 
  AES_DECRYPT(logTime,'b$Do^rK32C') logTime FROM prevent;
```

But look at the results here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c507a/3

My question is, why are those AES_DECRYPT values not the same as the Strings I INSERTed?

Comment: The SQLFiddle result you see is caused by SQLFiddle *displaying* the output using base64 encoding because the output type of `AES_DECRYPT()` is always blob, not string, so as far as it is concerned, the values may not correlate to valid characters so should not be treated (and displayed) as such. MySQL isn't really returning those values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(remoteAddr,'Wt@F4z5u#r')AS CHAR(50)) remoteAddr,
  CAST(AES_DECRYPT(logTime,'b$Do^rK32C')AS CHAR(50)) logTime FROM prevent;
```

Comment: because AES_DECRYPT method returns a binary string in your case.

Comment: Do you know if PHP's mysqli automatically convert binary string, because when I've used this technique with mysqli I didn't have to CAST?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to figure [this out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/796f6/1). Although your answer was vague, it pointed me in the right direction.